# Grails 2.4.2 - package-plugin --binary - rename the generated JAR

Tags: grails, plugins, jar, grails-2.4

I have a custom plugin which I want to package as a binary JAR. For doing so, I am executing a command as shown below:

`grails package-plugin --binary`

It's successfully generating the JAR file with the name of the form:

`grails-plugin-mycustom-plugin-1.0.jar`

I need to know, instead how can I generate a JAR file with a name of the form:

`mycustom-plugin-1.0.jar`

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Windows, open a command prompt and run

```
ren grails-plugin-mycustom-plugin-1.0.jar mycustom-plugin-1.0.jar
```

If you're using Linux/OSX/etc. open a shell and run

```
mv grails-plugin-mycustom-plugin-1.0.jar mycustom-plugin-1.0.jar
```

If you prefer a GUI, you can right-click on the file and rename it that way.

Comment: Thanks Burt, that works and I already did that :-) . However, I was wondering if there was a command or setting that could help me generate a JAR file with a custom name automatically, without having to follow this extra step.